# mergeDebugResources FAILED - Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'

Tags: android, react-native, npm, npx

Getting this error when running my `react native` project using `npm run android` .

```
The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.0.4) was tested up to compileSdk = 31

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
121 actionable tasks: 115 executed, 6 up-to-date
ERROR:/Users/Harry/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/76f4d2fb4fec518d9ceb089b87a31132/transformed/material-1.9.0/res/values/values.xml: Resource and asset merger: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/Harry/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/76f4d2fb4fec518d9ceb089b87a31132/transformed/material-1.9.0/res/values/values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
ERROR:/Users/Harry/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/76f4d2fb4fec518d9ceb089b87a31132/transformed/material-1.9.0/res/values/values.xml: Resource and asset merger: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/Harry/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/76f4d2fb4fec518d9ceb089b87a31132/transformed/material-1.9.0/res/values/values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

    at makeError (/Users/Harry/Documents/HumbeeRepos2/nativeapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/Harry/Documents/HumbeeRepos2/nativeapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/Harry/Documents/HumbeeRepos2/nativeapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/Harry/Documents/HumbeeRepos2/nativeapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I am not able to understand the error,

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/Harry/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/76f4d2fb4fec518d9ceb089b87a31132/transformed/material-1.9.0/res/values/values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'
```

System Specifications-

```
OS - MacOS Sonoma(14.0)
React Native version - 0.68.2
Emulator API - 34
```

PS- I have followed all the steps to setup react native environment mentioned in the official documentation of RN https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native

I tried running the project first time after cloning by setting up the environment using command

```
npm run android
```

But got above error.

Comment: same issue. Not able to fix it